# React.js: How do I send search query from react.js frontend to express.js backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to create a simple search bar using react.js which will connect to my express.js back-end which will return the correct data from the database back to the front-end. But I haven't managed to understand how to send my custom research from my search bar in react to my back-end.

This is my Search component so far, it just creates a simple search bar which is supposed to send the query to the back-end:

```
mport React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Search extends Component 
{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            result: [],
            filteredResult: []
        };
    }

    getData = () => {
        axios.get("/get-data").then(function(response){
            this.setState({
                result: response.data
            })
        });
    };

    handleInputChange = () => (
        this.setState({
            query: this.search.value
        }), () => {
            if (this.state.query) {
                this.getData()
            }
        }
    );

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getData();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input placeholder="Search for..." ref={input => this.search = input} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                <p>{this.state.query}</p>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I can connect to the `get-data` rout, but I haven't managed to figure out how to send my search query to it. I've searched for quite a while and every example I've seen used a bunch of different API's from the web which isn't very helpful for my case.

So, how do I receive my search query inside of my back-end? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the second param `.get()` of axios is `config` which can hold a `params` object for any query params to add to the request. The keys of that object is the query key and the value of the keys are the values of the query `?searchTerm=searchValue`. So it might look something like

```
getData = () => {
        axios.get(
           "/get-data",
           {
               params: {searchTerm: this.state.query}
           }
       ).then(function(response){
            this.setState({
                result: response.data
            })
        });
    };
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh, So simple yet so hard to find :] Thank you!
Sadly when I try to enter some input the input is limited to 8 chars for some bizarre reasons but that's a problem for another time :]